# Autohotkey, cycle through multiple matched window, is it possible?

Tags: autohotkey

I use the following autohotkey commands to bring EmEditor(a great text editor) to foreground.

```
^#1:: WinActivate, ahk_class EmEditorMainFrame3
```

However, when there are more than one EmEditor window(both with class name `EmEditorMainFrame3`), choosing the desire one to activate seems very challenging. I'd like to achieve such a result: Pressing Ctrl+Win+1 multiple times cycles me through different EmEditor windows, that is, each press of the hotkey activates a different EmEditor window. It's the best user experience I can imagine. Is that possible with Autohotkey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GroupAdd, EmEditorGroup, ahk_class EmEditorMainFrame3 

^#1:: GroupActivate EmEditorGroup   ; activate the next window in this window group
```

Comment: Great answer, and great Autohotkey feature. My own MEMO: ``GroupAdd, EmEditorGroup, ahk_class EmEditorMainFrame3`` should be written above any hotkey definition, i.e. in so called Auto-execute Section.

Comment: Awesome feature. Wish I knew this earlier!

Comment: This works, great! Does exactly what the first poster asked for :)